# Simple Javascript Loop Using input box variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm just trying to start with JavaScript and have put this little loop together. Providing I put 1 in the start box.. it works fine. If I put anything else though the loop itself never takes place.

According to the console my variables should all match the criteria for the loop to activate so I don't see the problem

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.clear();
  var Start = document.getElementById("Start").value
  console.log("Start=", Start)
  var End = document.getElementById("End").value
  console.log("End=", End)
  var which_one = document.getElementById("which_one").value
  console.log("which_one=", which_one)
  var i = Start;
  console.log("i=", i);

  var Counter_Array = "";
  console.log("Counter Array =", Counter_Array);
  var Counter_Array_Split = "";
  console.log("Counter Array Split = ", Counter_Array_Split)
  var Show_Me = "";
  console.log("Show Me = ", Show_Me)
  console.log("------Loop Starts------")
  for (; Start < End; Start++) {

    console.log("Start=", Start)

    console.log("i looped=", Start);
    Counter_Array += "," + Start
    var Counter_Array_Split = Counter_Array.split(',');

    console.log("CounterArrayLog=", Counter_Array);
    console.log("Counter Array Split = ", Counter_Array_Split);
    // sets all  elements with the id demo to have the value of the newURL variable
    document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = Counter_Array_Split;




  }
  console.log("------Loop Ends------")

  var Show_Me = Counter_Array_Split[which_one]
  console.log("Show Me = ", Show_Me)
  document.getElementById("my_val").innerHTML = Show_Me;

}
```

```css
.My_Form {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  ;
  border: 1;
  width: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.my_div {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  ;
  border: 1;
  width: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example Javascript Loop</h2>
<div class="My_Form">
  Start @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Start" id="Start" value="2"><br> End @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="fname" id="End" value="10"> <br> Show
  me the <input type="text" name="fname" id="which_one" value="5">th value in the array <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="my_div">
  The array built was
  <p id="array"></p>
  The Value picked was
  <p id="my_val"></p>
</div><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Click Me
</button>
<br>
```

Comment: Can you add a working example using the StackOverflow snippet tool?

Comment: I updated your pasted code to a snippet instead

Comment: You have a lot of redefined variables everywhere. Too much things to talk about here... I guess that you need to start with a JavaScript tutorial before going with things that you don't really understand.

Comment: `"2" < "10"` is false.  try using `parseInt(Start, 10) & parseInt(End, 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use integers in the for loop, by default you use string, so you need to parse it first.
1st problem: '5' < '10' this is false.
2nd problem: '5'++ will convert it to 5 and only after that will be incremented.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.clear();
  var Start = parseInt( document.getElementById("Start").value, 10)
  console.log("Start=", Start)
  var End = parseInt(document.getElementById("End").value, 10)
  console.log("End=", End)
  var which_one = document.getElementById("which_one").value
  console.log("which_one=", which_one)
  var i = Start;
  console.log("i=", i);

  var Counter_Array = "";
  console.log("Counter Array =", Counter_Array);
  var Counter_Array_Split = "";
  console.log("Counter Array Split = ", Counter_Array_Split)
  var Show_Me = "";
  console.log("Show Me = ", Show_Me)
  console.log("------Loop Starts------")
  for (; Start < End; Start++) {

    console.log("Start=", Start)

    console.log("i looped=", Start);
    Counter_Array += "," + Start
    var Counter_Array_Split = Counter_Array.split(',');

    console.log("CounterArrayLog=", Counter_Array);
    console.log("Counter Array Split = ", Counter_Array_Split);
    // sets all  elements with the id demo to have the value of the newURL variable
    document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = Counter_Array_Split;




  }
  console.log("------Loop Ends------")

  var Show_Me = Counter_Array_Split[which_one]
  console.log("Show Me = ", Show_Me)
  document.getElementById("my_val").innerHTML = Show_Me;

}
```

```css
.My_Form {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  ;
  border: 1;
  width: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.my_div {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  ;
  border: 1;
  width: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example Javascript Loop</h2>
<div class="My_Form">
  Start @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Start" id="Start" value="2"><br> End @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="fname" id="End" value="10"> <br> Show
  me the <input type="text" name="fname" id="which_one" value="5">th value in the array <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="my_div">
  The array built was
  <p id="array"></p>
  The Value picked was
  <p id="my_val"></p>
</div><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Click Me
</button>
<br>
```

Comment: @Keith Thanks, I edited, however if the user want to use other type, like hex then with this can't be used.